# Notifying Kafka topic about pod status in preStop hook

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka

Is there a way to send a message to Kafka topic from preStop hook? Kafka message should include pod stats like name and total up time.

Comment: Of course! In a preStop hook you can execute a command inside the container. That command could send the Kafka message. Which containers do you want to send the message from? What tools and libraries are available in those containers?

Comment: How do I get access to pod stats like name etc?

Comment: From where? You could use the command line tool `kubectl get pods` or the Kubernetes API too.